# gethostbyname and gethostbyaddress - location of structs in memory

Tags: c, networking, network-programming

Both functions return a `struct hostent *`. 
What I want to know is where exactly are the structs created / stored in memory?

My guess is that it has to be on the heap, but then the man page doesn't warn us about freeing the pointer returned.

It can't be on the stack, otherwise when the function returns that address is no longer valid...

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, both functions are considered obsolete, and should be replaced by `getaddrinfo` & `getnameinfo`.

As for the memory, it should be considered as temporary static data that shouldn't be freed. The spec itself doesn't declare how that should be implemented.

In [Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524(v=vs.85).aspx):

> The memory for the hostent structure returned by the gethostbyname function is allocated internally by the Winsock DLL from thread local storage.

In Linux (from this [manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/gethostbyname)):

> The functions gethostbyname() and gethostbyaddr() may return pointers to static data, which may be overwritten by later calls. Copying the struct hostent does not suffice, since it contains pointers; a deep copy is required.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows, it's stored in per-thread data that is automatically reclaimed when the thread exits. This enables multiple threads to call the APIs without stomping on each other. Of course, any individual thread cannot expect the `hostent` to be maintained across calls.

I don't know how it works in Unix-like environments.